# BibTeX does not recognize DOI

Tags: bibtex

I receive the error message

```
Warning--unrecognized DOI value [doi:10.1145/1465482.1465560]
```

although

```
http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1465560
```

seems to be a correct DOI. What is wrong?

Comment: We are going to need some more info here. Is the warning coming from a BibTeX run, and if so from what BibTeX style (`.bst` file)? Alternatively, is this an editor warning from some BibTeX database management program?

Comment: The `DOI` value should be `10.1145/1465482.1465560` instead of `doi:10.1145/1465482.1465560`...

Comment: @Paul Gaborit Thank you. The less is more in this case. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `DOI` field should be `10.1145/1465482.1465560` instead of `doi:10.1145/1465482.1465560`.